# Gems install correctly, but then don't show up in gem list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I recently switched from rvm to rbenv for Ruby version management, and since I've been running into all sorts of problems with gems.  If I run `gem list` it only lists about 10 gems, all of which are system defaults.  But when I run `bundle install` in a project with a Gemfile, it lists a ton of other gems and says they were successfully installed.  Then I can't run them from the command line or require them in ruby files!

Output from `gem list`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.3.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

And then from `bundle install`

```
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.5
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.1
Using activesupport 4.1.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using activemodel 4.1.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.1
Using bond 0.5.1
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using ripl 0.7.1
Using ripl-multi_line 0.3.1
Using ripl-rack 0.2.1
Using shotgun 0.9
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sinatra 1.4.5
Using sinatra-activerecord 2.0.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using tux 0.3.0
Using bundler 1.6.3
Your bundle is complete!
```

My `gem env` is as follows:

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.3.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Alex/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/Alex/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/bin
     - /Users/Alex/.rbenv/libexec
     - /Users/Alex/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/Alex/.dotfiles/bin
```

The listed gem paths contain those 10 or so gems that I see when running `gem list`.  But I know I have other gems, because bundler says there's a ton that are installed successfully.  I think they're somewhere outside my gem path, but I have no idea where.

How should I proceed?  I don't know where these gems are installed.  I'm reluctant to start adding paths to my gem_path, as this shouldn't be necessary.  Is there a way to tell bundler to force a reinstall of the gems, so they are forced into the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` listed in the `gem env`?

I'm on a Mac running Mavericks, and rbenv was installed using homebrew.

Comment: Can you go to the directory of where you ran "bundle install" and run "bundle show rails" (it doesn't have to be rails, it can be any gem in the Gemfile). That will tell you the directory of the gem.

Comment: Great! Thank you.  It seems all the bundled gems are installed to `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems`.  Should I just manually put this path on my $GEM_PATH?  There must be a better, way, no?

Comment: You don't want to do that since it defeats the purpose of using rbenv. How did you install rbenv? When you run "type rbenv" what do you get?

Comment: It says rbenv is a function. And I have the rbenv init line in my .bashrc as well.

Comment: I think you need to install "bundler" for the rbenv version of Ruby. Try doing "gem install bundler" and then "bundle install". I think that since your rbenv version of Ruby does not have bundler but your system Ruby does, it is falling back to the system Ruby bundler.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work...I think `gem` just found my already installed version of bundler as the "installation" was pretty much instant.  Maybe I just remove it and force it.

Comment: `which bundle` might give you the path to the `bundle` executable you use (not sure how thats in MacOS X). But afaics, the issue is more or less solved. Could you or @kcdragon formulate and accept an answer ... three years later? :)